# Appcelerator - Android App Deployment

Tags: android, mobile, appcelerator-mobile

I am trying to deploy an android app to a local, plugged-in device. I'm using Appcelerator Studio as my IDE, and have been having a lot of trouble getting the app onto the local device.

The android device has USB-debugging turned on, is plugged into an USB port on the back of the machine (on a mac, the only ports are on the back), and the device is set to trust unauthorized apps (not from the app store).

I've tried just about any so called 'solution' that people have posted before, and I'm still struggling with this.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.